# Drawing an arrow cursor on user dragging in XNA/MonoGame

Tags: xna, touch, monogame

I am writing a touch enabled game in MonoGame (XNA-like API) and would like to display a an arrow 'cursor' as user is making a drag gesture from point A to point B.
I am not sure on how to correctly approach this problem. It seems that its best to just draw a sprite from A to B and scale it as required. This would however mean it gets stretched as user continues dragging gesture in one direction.
Or maybe its better to dynamically render the arrow so it looks better?

Comment: it really depends on what the user trying to achieve with the gesture.

Answer (score 3):

You may split the arrow into a shaft and a head. Then you just enlarge the shaft and add the head later on. This will prevent your arrowhead from being stretched and if you pick a shaft image which will not show any signs of strechting (i.e. a rectangle) the whole process will be hidden.